# Dynamically generate a list of attributes in Terraform

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create multiple resources of the same type, but depending on the subtype, they will have different sets of attributes.
The list of attributes and their values are stored in a CSV file, the attribute value is empty when not applicable. I load the CSV in a list attribute_list.
E. g. if I create one resource only manually it would be:

```
resource "snowflake_file_format" "example_file_format" {
  name        = "EXAMPLE_FILE_FORMAT"
  database    = "EXAMPLE_DB"
  schema      = "EXAMPLE_SCHEMA"
  format_type = "CSV"
  field_delimiter = "|"
 }
```

In this case field_delimiter attribute is applicable for CSV type only.
Then if I need many of resources of the same type (says CSV):

```
locals {
  formats_file = file("formats.csv")
  formats_list = csvdecode(local.attributes_file)
  formats_number= length(local.attributes_list)
}


resource "snowflake_file_format" "example_file_formats" {
  count = attributes_number
  name        = attributes_list[count.index]["name"]
  database    = attributes_list[count.index]["database"]
  schema      = attributes_list[count.index]["schema"]
  format_type = attributes_list[count.index]["format_type"]
  field_delimiter = attributes_list[count.index]["delimiter"]
 }
```

The issue comes when I have more than one format, say csv and json. They don't have the same set of attributes, so I wonder if I can have a solution like the one suggested by Daniel. A non satisfactory solution exists:

```
resource "file_format" "example_file_formats" {
 count = formats_number
 subtype = "subtype1"
 name = formats_list[count.index]["name"]
 option1 = formats_list[count.index]["option1"]
}
resource "type_of_resource" "some_names" {
 count = attribute_list_length
 subtype = "subtype2"
 name = attribute_list[count.index]["name"]
 option2 = attribute_list[count.index]["option2"]
}
```

But this forces me to have two different runswhile I wanted to run this in a single run instead of managing two different var files.

Is there anything that let me generate the attribute dynamically. Something that looks like:

```
resource "type_of_resource" "some_names" {
    count = formats_number

    for_each element in formats_list[count.index] #for each format loop through attributes
     {
         element.key = element.value
    }
}
```

Knowing that the target structure doesn't have nested elements as you can see in the top example.

Comment: The last example you've given cannot work because `for_each` and `count` arguments cannot be used interchangeably. You can use either `count` or `for_each` but I feel more details are missing to have a definitive answer.

Comment: it will be much easier if you can craft a reproducible example, why don't you use real resources and give a sample  of your attribute variables

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I certainly can do that. The reasons I haven't done in first place is I wanted the focus to be on the generic issue rather than on a specific that can be technically worked around.

Comment: @MarkoE I wanted to use count tu loop through the array of maps, so each map represents a list of options that belong to the same resource. Then the for_each is intended to loop through a single map to assign the attributes.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda added more details, and made it more specific

Comment: can you provide samples of the csv and json files ... you say they don't have the same set of attributes, if there is not "standard" what you are asking will be very difficult

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Terraform provides the ability to dynamically generate resources from a data source.

In this example, we will use a CSV file which contains a list of resources and their attributes as our data source. We will use the `csvdecode` function to parse the CSV file and the `dynamic` block to generate the resources.

The code below shows an example of how to generate multiple resources of the same type, but with different sets of attributes, using a CSV file as our data source.

```
data "csv" "example" {
  type = "list"
  separator = ","
  filename = "example.csv"
}

resource "example_resource" "example" {
  count = length(data.csv.example.list)

  dynamic "attribute" {
    for_each = data.csv.example.list[count.index]

    content {
      name  = attribute.value.name
      value = attribute.value.value
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, the `data` block will read the CSV file and parse it into a list of maps. The `dynamic` block will then iterate over each map in the list and create a resource with the attributes specified in the CSV file.

This allows us to dynamically generate multiple resources of the same type, but with different sets of attributes, using a CSV file as our data source.

Comment: Thanks for that. How will one equivalent  resource look like if created manually? Will there be an "attribute" block or just a flat structure? I'm asking because my resource has a flat structure.

Comment: @MehdiSidiBoumedine  this is exactly the point in my comment, this answer only works with those resources that have attributes that "support" this dynamic syntax like this case: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_environment#example-with-options
\

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't look to work for snowflake file formats